# When a Paypal billing subscription is charged for the 2nd time, what event is fired to the webhook?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Let's say I created a `billing plan`, then `billing agreement` (i.e. subscription) that chrages monthly and infinitely, via the `Paypal REST API`, and provided I have a webhook that listens on all events: what event type will be fired next month when the client is charged?

Here's a [list of all the possible events](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/event-names/), I tried many of them in the [simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/webhooksSimulator/), but none returns something that resembles an ID of the associated `billing agreement`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I need to know this answer as well and the documentation is mediocre at best.

Comment: @CWitty yeah just added an asnwer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the hard way. It is `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`

You get the billing agreement id via `event.resource.billing_agreement_id`

Comment: Thanks a bunch man, I couldn't figure this one out. Im really not a fan of PayPal, especially their docs.